# Kotlin: Init function and variable initialization

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building a component for my app and I started to use `init` function instead of constructor more often, but now weird thing is happening. If I call function inside `init` function to initialize list, it throws `NullPointerException` on that list. Is `init` function executed before variables are initialized in particular class?

Exception is thrown in `removeAllViews`.

Code:

```
init {
        createViews()
    }

    private var viewList = mutableListOf<ViewGroup>()
    private fun createViews(){
        removeAllViews()
        list.forEach { addItem(it) }
        changeViewsState(true)
    }

    private fun removeAllViews(){
        parent.removeAllViews()
        viewList.clear()
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [init block position in class in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447842/init-block-position-in-class-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this section fo the offcial documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

> During an instance initialization, the initializer blocks are executed
> in the same order as they appear in the class body, interleaved with
> the property initializers.

So you should put the variable declaration before the `init`:

```
private var viewList = mutableListOf<ViewGroup>()

init {
    createViews()
}
private fun createViews(){
    removeAllViews()
    list.forEach { addItem(it) }
    changeViewsState(true)
}

private fun removeAllViews(){
    parent.removeAllViews()
    viewList.clear()
}
```